# When my visa expires in Germany, can I still be a tourist for 90 days?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, us-citizens

I am a U.S. citizen currently in Germany with a residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel), which expires at the end of September. But, I want to stay here for another few weeks to travel.

After my permit expires, am I allowed to stay as a tourist for another 90 days?

I was in Italy until June 15, returned to the U.S. and then arrived in Berlin on June 23 with my permit. I already booked a ticket in mid October and I don't know whether I should change it to September, because I don't know if I'm legally allowed to stay for another few weeks. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: I imagine you will have to leave the Schengen area and then return to start your 90 day visa free entry as a US citizen.

Comment: This question may be better answered on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/